# How to run vanilla javascript after react loads?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a script and using react as the playground. Long story short the script will be a standalone chrome extension that will be used to manipulate websites (those react powered also).

So inside the react project, in `public/index.html` I have this:

```
    ....
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="./extension/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And inside `main.js` I want to wait for react to load the data into `#root` (as it does) and then I want to start my own code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if(window.localStorage.getItem('highlights')){
    makeSelection(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('highlights')))
  }
})
```

But that's not working.

(Not, I can't use react hooks, this will be totally independent of react, I just want to make sure when it runs in a react site it works)

Answer (score 0):

You can start some timeOut to check if #root has empty innerHTML, and if it is not run your code

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

first, in `extension/main.js` file I will wrap all my code in global function let's call it on `onAppDidMount`

```
window.onAppDidMount = function(){
    ... // all main.js code here
}
```

and in the root component, I will call this global function after root component mounted

```
class App extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount(){
         window.onAppDidMount();
    }
    ...
}
```